# Preferences: Change time it takes to animate to specific Numpad view

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I remember there was a setting in `preferences` where you can change the time it animates to the selected `Numpad` view. Like if you press `Numpad 7`, the camera animates to that view, i believe the default value is 0.5 seconds. Where do i change it? i tried searching it but it seems **ungoogleable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest version (3.2) this setting is called *Smooth view*, under *Navigation*. It's in milliseconds, so the default value is 0.2 seconds. I'm not surprised you didn't find it, the name is... not descriptive.

Note the max value is hardcoded to 1000 ms (1 second) and setting it to 0 disables the animation.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer! that's exactly what i was looking for!